# update a calender event in outlook using php

Tags: php

I want to updates the calendar events in outlook that is already present or sent else add the new event to the calendar. I went through it and found difficult to do it, Is there a way to do this using php?

Comment: I don't think you can detect if a specific event is already in an outlook calendar of a client. So you only can send the new one and the user has to replace it itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code. I have already used and it works fine for MS Outlook 2007 also.

BEGIN:VCALENDAR

VERSION:2.0

PRODID:-//SYFADIS//PORTAIL FORMATION//FR

METHOD:REQUEST

BEGIN:VEVENT

UID:ACS_32657@abcd.com

SEQUENCE:3

DTSTAMP:20131109T154911Z

ORGANIZER:event@abcd.com

DTSTART:20131109T164907

DTEND:20131109T170000

SUMMARY:Test Update

DESCRIPTION:Test Description

STATUS:CONFIRMED

END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR

You have to specify the following:
1) METHOD:REQUEST
2) ORGANIZER:xxxxxxxx
3) UID
4) SEQUENCE: